# Updating/Patching a Local Post with Google My Business API and PHP

Tags: php, curl, google-my-business-api

I'm trying to update/patch a specific GMB Local Post using curl.
For this example, I'm only trying to update the *summary* of the post.

Here's my code:

```
    $url = "https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/v4/".$postId."?updateMask=1";

    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PATCH');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $pQuery = array(
        "summary" => $postMessage
    );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($pQuery));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array( 'Authorization: Bearer '.$access_token.'', 'Content-Type: application/json', 'Content-Length: ' . strlen(json_encode($pQuery))));

    $updatePostDetails = curl_exec($ch);
```

I get no error, but the response body I get is the same Local Post as before, ignoring the new *summary* I updated.

I assume my issue comes from the *updateMask* parameter, but I can't find how to make it work.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

updateMask parameter expects path of the field that needs change. So you should provide as updateMask=summary. So your URL should be as

```
   $url = "https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/v4/".$postId."?updateMask=summary";
```

Comment: I'm trying to patch the actionType and url in the callToAction object too, any idea on how to achieve this along with the summary? Thank you.

Comment: @mckaymental You can do so by having parameter updateMask=callToAction.actionType,callToAction.url,summary